# Unable to add where condition in sql statement using datatable

Tags: php, sql, ajax, datatable

I'm getting an uncaught error

> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE lastname like '%%' OR firstname like '%%' OR middlename like '%%' OR em...'

The code works by removing where clause in query.
I want to get the data with a value of 0 in 'active' column.

```
$result= array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ndi3670 WHERE active = 0 ";

$totalQuery = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$total_all_rows = mysqli_num_rows($totalQuery);

$columns = array(
    0 => 'empid',
    1 => 'lastname',
    2 => 'firstname',
    3 => 'middlename',
);

if(isset($_POST['search']['value']))
{
    $search_value = $_POST['search']['value'];
    $sql .= " WHERE lastname like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR firstname like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR middlename like '%".$search_value."%'";
    $sql .= " OR empid like '%".$search_value."%'";
}
```

It seems I'm having error in where() function

Answer (score 1):

You already have `WHERE` in the original `$sql` value, you can't use that again. You need to use `AND` to add additional conditions, not another `WHERE`.

You should also put parentheses around the `OR` conditions so they'll be grouped together.

And you shouldn't substitute a variable into the SQL, you should use a prepared statement with parameters.

```
$result= array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ndi3670 WHERE active = 0 ";

$totalQuery = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$total_all_rows = mysqli_num_rows($totalQuery);

$columns = array(
    0 => 'empid',
    1 => 'lastname',
    2 => 'firstname',
    3 => 'middlename',
);

if(isset($_POST['search']['value']))
{
    $search_value = '%' . $_POST['search']['value'] . '%';
    $sql .= " AND (lastname like ?";
    $sql .= " OR firstname like ?";
    $sql .= " OR middlename like ?";
    $sql .= " OR empid like ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $search_value, $search_value, $search_value, $search_value);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a WHERE condition in your initial assignment to $sql: (WHERE active = 0 ); then you append another `WHERE lastname...`. Replace the latter one with  `AND (` and append a closing bracket `)` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 WHEREs in your final sql statement. When you're appending another WHERE to the original string, it becomes something like `SELECT * FROM ndi3670 WHERE active = 0  WHERE lastname like '%".$search_value."%'`.

You could rewrite the statement to something like this:

```
if( isset( $_POST['search']['value'] ) )
{
    $search_value = $_POST['search']['value'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `ndi3670` WHERE `active` = 0 AND";
    // When using both AND and OR like this, wrap the group of ORs in parenthesis
    $sql .= " (`lastname` LIKE '%$search_value%'";
    $sql .= " OR `firstname` LIKE '%$search_value%'";
    $sql .= " OR `middlename` LIKE '%$search_value%'";
    $sql .= " OR `empid` LIKE '%$search_value%')";
}
```